# How to retrieve information about the current user with Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase in an application written in Swift and cannot understand how to have the email of the current logged user. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is an easy google question. http://www.appcoda.com/firebase/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on how you are authenticating (password? Facebook?) but a code snippet will probably suffice.

All of the user data is stored in an FAuthData variable authData, and within that, there's a providerData dictionary that contains specific information.

To read a current users email, define authData as as your-firebase.authData

```
let email = authData.providerData[@"email"]
```

There's a section on the Firebase website [Email and Password Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/password.html) that defines what is contained within the authData variable.